# How do I search mysql table so it only returns dvds that star an optional list of actors which is stored in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm in two minds whether to post this as I've been thinking all day and can't think of an easy way to express the question, so sorry about the title.

I'm new to mysql and php. I wanted to create something very simple with just a couple of tables but I didn't realize what I wanted to do was not covered in the book I just read.

I created a dvd database. The table dvds contains a title, a genre, and a unique auto increment id.

I have another table called staring, which contains an actor, and the dvdId.

I want the user to be able to have the option of searching for dvds based on the title, the genre or by which actors starred in the dvd.

The bit I am having trouble with is I don't know how to add to the query so that it only returns dvds that contain all the actors, if there are actors listed. This is what I have so far and works as I expected.

```
function getDvds($title, $genre, $staring) { 
    // $staring will be an array of actor names

    $query = "SELECT * FROM dvds WHERE 1";

    if (!empty($title)) {
        $query .= " AND title = '$title'";
    }

    if (!empty($genre)) {
        $query .= " AND genre = '$genre'";
    }

    $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);
}
```

So now I need to only return the result if it contains all of the actors the user inputed. If the user has entered actor names I have to check that it only returns dvds that have those actors in it. I'm so confused at how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to use joins since you want to pull info from multiple tables.

If `$starring` is an array of names, you can do this:

```
if (!empty($starring)) {
    $query .= " INNER JOIN actors on actors.dvdId = dvds.dvdId WHERE";
    foreach( $starring as $name )
         $query .= " starring LIKE '%$name%' OR";
    substr( $query, 0, -3 );  //Remove last OR
}
```

The logic here isn't perfect (will match all DVDs with any of the supplied actors), but I know this will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you that looks good. I will have a play around with it. To me it looks like I should be able to change OR to an AND and it will work as expected. My mind is tired so I I'm going to come back to it tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: If you change it to `AND`, then it will try to find all those names in the same entry of your `starring` table.

Comment: So where you say that it will match all dvds with any of the supplied actors, does that mean it doesn't take into consideration the title of the dvd or the genre? If so I'm still unsure of how to do that.

Comment: You're probably better off using the `LIKE` operator, unless you are searching for *exact* matches of the Title, etc... Also, updating your question with the structure of your `dvds` and `starring`  (or `actors`) tables in MySQL will net you a clearer answer.

Comment: I had to mess about with it a bit. Mainly I had to only use one where and join the tables first. In the end a typical query featurng made up film name looks like this.

Comment: $query = "SELECT DISTINCT title, dvds.dvdid FROM dvds
       INNER JOIN actors ON dvds.dvdid=actors.dvdid WHERE
       (name = 'Bob Smith' OR name = 'Fred Flintstone') AND title='Rocket'"; Thanks for your help.